# Why "partner" instead of "wife\husband"?

Tags: word-choice

What's wrong with the words "wife" and "husband"? Why do people instead use "partner" more and more often?

Comment: It's a cultural phenomenon. There's no purely linguistic reason.

Comment: Some people also use spouse

Comment: wife/husband/spouse all imply a legal union of two people, either in the eyes of the church or the eyes of the state. 'partner' on the other hand, does  not necessarily, and is often used by couples who want to make that distinction.

Comment: Well, when you are a couple saying partner sounds as if you don't love each other but only do sexual stuff and discuss financial questions.

Comment: @SovereignSun: I think you have a flawed definition. While "partner" can refer to a sexual relationship, that is not its only meaning. Consider [defintions 1.2 and 1.3 here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/partner).

Comment: @lms Well, it's certainly true that "partner" is used in other contexts. A "partner" can be someone with whom you share ownership of a business. It can be used in a general sense for someone that you are working closely with, like, "Now students, everyone choose a partner for this next class project." But the question specifically asks about "partner" as an alternative to "husband/wife".

Comment: @Jay: That's true, but not in my opinion relevant to the question (since the OP asked specifically about the wife/husband-like usage).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that it's all-inclusive - it avoids any labels of gender, marital status or sexuality.

Also, in this day and age, not all couples decide to get married (and unfortunately, in many countries, couples in homosexual relationships don't have the option to get married), so the term 'partner' can seem more appropriate to some in terms of describing the stage of the relationship. Imagine a couple from the scenario above, who can't, or chooses not to get married. Boyfriend or girlfriend can imply a less serious relationship. 'Partner' implies a more permanent state.

Comment: To me it sounds very impolite.

Comment: @SovereignSun: It's perfectly normal, no impoliteness about it. There can be the implication that the partners aren't married, but otherwise it's no less polite than wife, husband, [spouse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spouse), or [significant other](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/significant_other).

Comment: @SovereignSun - I guess that's a matter of perspective, rather than a point of English.

Comment: "Impolite" in what sense? I suppose if in conversation you referred to a woman's husband as her "partner", she might object and say "No, he's not my partner, he's my husband. We're married". But if you are talking about two people who have an on-going sexual relationship but are not married, of course you can't properly call them husband and wife, so "partner" is about as polite as it gets. Presumably more polite than "the person you are living in sin with" or "your f*** buddy".

Comment: @Jay Exactly. When they are not husband and wife ))) But I hear psychiatrists often say that to married couples and often other people.

Comment: @SovereignSun Sure. Some people use "partner" as a polite way to refer to unmarried but cohabiting couples. Others use it as a catch-all for any sexual relationship. And here's where it gets social/political: some deliberately apply it to both married and unmarried, straight and gay couples, in a way that implies that these are essentially equivalent relationships. If you think that all sexual relationships ARE morally and socially equivalent, then this makes perfect sense. If you believe they are not, than this demeans marriage.

Comment: @Jay it's a personal matter I guess. What's the most appropriate definition of the word partner that means a loving couple?